# Granted Authority List is Empty after Migration to Spring Security 6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, migration

After the migration to spring boot 3 and spring security 6, I have issues to authorize my anonymous authentification properly. Iam using an oath2 resource server and azure active directory. The granted authority list is always empty. do i have to tweak my web security configuration somehow?

snippet from WebSecurityConfig class after migration:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    log.debug("Configuring HTTP Security");
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors()
        .and()
        .headers()
        .frameOptions().disable()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests((authorize) ->
            authorize.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/sf/**", "/assets/**", "/resources/**", "/built/**", "/ui/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new RolesToRightsConverterFilter(s3RSpringConfig), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new Slf4jMDCFilter(authService, tracingService), RolesToRightsConverterFilter.class))
        .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(new JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationConverter());

    return http.build();
  }
```

and the relevant part of application.yml:

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/${add_tenant_id}/v2.0'
          audiences: '${add_client_id:xxx}'

  cloud:
    azure:
      active-directory:
        credential:
          client-id: ${add_client_id:xxx}
          client-secret: xxx
        profile:
          tenant-id: ${add_tenant_id:xxx}
        jwk-set-cache-lifespan: 10m
        jwk-set-cache-refresh-time: 10m
        enabled: true
```

the xxx is just a placeholder for the actual ID.

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Comment: same error for me